# codeigniter links and controls

Tags: php, codeigniter

by all ways and solutions I cant make link 
,I wanna make links to another page  I cant 
,please check my files and tell me where the error
,when I write link manual 
like 
,localhost/demo/index.php/home/contactUs
it work and open page without any css or js files

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['contactUs'] = "home/contactUs";
$route['Home(/:any)'] = "Home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

.htaccess

controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url'); 
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('postsModel');
    $data['whywe'] = $this->postsModel->getPostByCode('post1');

    $this->load->model('infoModel');
    $info_data['fan_info']= $this->infoModel->getInfoToEdit(1);


    $this->load->view('site/static/header',$info_data);
    $this->load->view('site/home',$data);
    $this->load->view('site/static/footer',$info_data);
}
```

Comment: what is the url when you use `<?php echo site_url('Home/contactUs')?>`

Comment: It's a same error and repeat the link twice likr <br> localhost/demo/localhost/demo

Comment: define `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/demo';`

Comment: I defined it and try is a same

Comment: read https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: @urfusion Put slash at the end of base url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('Home/contactUs'); ?>">CLICK ME</a>
```

Comment: A good answer means leaving an explanation of what this does and in this case where the author should include it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the quotes. change your link in header as follows :

```
<li>
   <a href="<?php echo site_url('Home/contactUs')?>">CLICK ME</a>  
</li>
```

Comment: try to echo `site_url()` and check if it is correct or not

Comment: Is correct but when echo site_url it will repeat localhost /demo